# How to show "out of stock" in ONE category only while hiding them from all other categories?

Tags: magento2, catalog

I am trying to display out of stock product in only one category. 
I have already change admin setting

> "display out of stock"  - No

any idea how to display it in one category.

Comment: Are you able to achieve this? If yes, could you please share your solution? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Create page like out of stock poduct.
1) In that page call block in side the layout part.
2) Block have logic like that given only out of stock product list.

Comment: i have fetch out of stock product in one category.